# Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XX.XX port 9000: Connection refused

Tags: python, curl, flask, flask-restful

I created a web service and tried to run it on the test server (since dont need any type of security) , it worked for the localhost then i tried to forward port 9000 from my router & the port was successfully forwarded so , i sent a request to that web service from a local machine with a **public ip** and the service returned the correct result.

My Flask app run command :

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9000)
```

Request from **Local PC**:

```
C:\Users\taha\Downloads\Facial-Emotion-Detection-master\Facial-Emotion-Detection-master>curl -F "file=@images/Sample1.jpg" http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:9000/Img_Emotion/
```

Result:

```
{"angry": 0, "disgusted": 0, "fearful": 0, "happy": 99.97, "sad": 0, "surprised": 0, "neutral": 0.03}
```

but when i tried it from some **external PC** it says

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XX.XX port 9000: Connection refused
```

Moreover I have turned my router and window firewall off but still the same problem

Comment: I would recommend not doing it on reserved ports for os try like 3000 and make sure your firewall excepts the connection on port

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari tried on port 9000 too still same problem , how to check if the firewall is accepting  it or not ? (my router and windows firewall are off)

Comment: Not sure about windows about firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the client's side , the client was using proxy which was later removed & it worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 1):

In your router settings, try putting your machine (the one running the server) in a DMZ (demilitarized zone). Also double-check your firewalls (specifially your Windows firewall).

Answer (score -1):

It was solved when I turned off my windows firewall.

Comment: Consider adding some instruction on why this works, how to do this and perhaps the security concerns of such an action.